# Visual Studio copiar arquivo para o diretório de saída

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Olá!

No meu projeto eu tenho um arquivo xml e quero copiar esse arquivo para o diretório de saída na hora da compilação para que ele fique junto com o arquivo executável e demais arquivos. Para isso criei um evento de pós-compilação para copiar esse arquivo para o diretório de saída. Mas ao compilar está ocorrendo falha no evento.
Estou quase certo que deve ser um erro relacionado a caminho do arquivo mas não estou certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis a instrução de evento que estou tentando:

`copy SqlCommands.xml $(OutDir)`

Erro:

`Gravidade  Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de supressão
Erro        The command "copy SqlCommands.xml ..\bin\Debug\" exited with code 1.    FoxVideoManagerBackend  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4714`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nas propriedades do arquivo não tem a opção de copiar localmente? Faz o que você precisa de forma automática

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com essa [documentação](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx), que eu acho que se aplica a seu caso tb,  esse exited with code 1 é: ***No files were found to copy.***

Esse comando abaixo é como eu faço o copy em um projeto meu, ele funciona perfeitamente aqui:

```
powershell -Command "xcopy '$(ProjectDir)Content\a\*' '$(ProjectDir)DIRPARACOPIA\Content\Content\a\' /s /e"
```

Sobre corrigir o seu, eu realmente não consigo usando só as informações da pergunta, talvez o código todo ajude mais.

De qualquer forma eu vou chutar que esse "SqlCommands.xml" não está no diretório root de onde ele roda o comando, tenta colocar o caminho todo para o SQL ou usar as variáveis `$(ProjectDir)`, etc.

Comment: A resposta do Ton Angelo resolveu de maneira mais simples, mas também funcionou através dos eventos usando as variáveis `ProjecDir` e `TargetDir`.
Aproveitando o gancho da pergunta, pq faz-se necessário envolver as variáveis entre aspas?
Estou meio enferrujado sobre DOS, mas será devido aos espaços em nomes de pastas?

Comment: A resposta dele tirou onda, isso sim hahaha, no meu caso eu não uso porque eu dou um `-replace` no meio do caminho aí e tal. Olha sobre as aspas eu vou confessar que estava tomando erro nisso até que um amigo aqui bateu o olho, falou dos espaços e mandou colocar as aspas. Funcionou perfeitamente e eu não pesquisei mais do que o que ele falou.